# Unclear behavior of a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Title!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = false;    
            function foo() {
                alert (x);  
                return true;
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                $('#my_form').attr('onsubmit', foo);
                $('a').click(function(e) {
                    x = true;
                    $('#my_form').submit();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="my_form" action="">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'a' click function sets the variable x to be true, why it is false when foo() is run?

Comment: are you binding the "foo" function to "onsubmit" ?

Comment: Please do not use inline event handlers with jQuery. It is more complicated and does not work the same way as jQuery events.

Comment: make `window.onload` to `document.ready`

Comment: @: Fires earlier, sure, but otherwise make no difference to this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw JS events do not work the same way as jQuery events. Don't mix the two.

`attr` allows you to supply a function as the second parameter. That is why your code fires immediately. It is simply assigning the return value to the attribute, e.g. `onsubmit="true"`

Your current fiddle fires the foo handler as soon as you run this line:

```
$('#my_form').attr('onsubmit', foo)
```

You probably meant something like this (or equivalent), but it does not work either:

```
$('#my_form').attr('onsubmit', "javascript:foo()");
```

Here is the jQuery equivalent:

```
var x = false;

function foo() {
    alert (x);  
    return true;
}

$(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit(foo);
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        x = true;
        $('#my_form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lf8hhwvq/

The shortcut DOM ready handler I use above, `$(function(){...});`, also acts as an IIFE, so you can move the related code inside it:

```
$(function () {
    var x = false;

    function foo() {
        alert(x);
        return true;
    }
    $('#my_form').submit(foo);
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        x = true;
        $('#my_form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lf8hhwvq/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with this code. First of all, you are mixing old parts of the DOM API with jQuery. In your case I would recommend just to stick to jQuery. Amongst other things:

- You should put all render-blocking code (that includes code that changes the DOM) before the `</body>` Tag, not in the `<head>`. Depending on the size of your JavaScript dependencies, your page will load very slowly.
- Don't use `window.load =`, especially if jQuery has its very own `$(document).ready()` function, that probably meets your needs even better.
- If you want to set an event handler, don't try to set it with the `attr` function. That's a very old way of doing it and also the **source of your problem**. Use the [jQuery `.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead (the jQuery equivalent of `.addEventListener`).
- If you can avoid it, don't use global variables. Wrap all your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) instead.

Thus, your code becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="my_form" action="">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    <script src="/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = false;

        function foo() {
            alert (x);  
            return true;
        }

        $('#my_form').on('submit', foo);
        $('a').on('click', function(e) {
            x = true;
            $('#my_form').submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvaOLR

Comment: Note: The code shown is not "render blocking, so placement is arbitrary. Also, using `on` is overkill for the most basic events like these as `.submit()` and `.click()` provide the same functionality (in less characters). For the code shown the DOM ready will also do as a scope wrapper (so no extra IIFE required).

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, but usually scripts loaded in the (without the `async` attribute) will stop rendering until the script has loaded. That is the definition of render-blocking, no? Yes, `document.ready` is enough, IFEE isn't necessary. `on` is a matter of style preference, consistency is what counts.

Comment: "loaded" does not apply to inline scripts.. it is already "loaded" :) Consistency is very good, but size *is* important too ;)

Comment: I'm talking about `<script src="/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`. That is being loaded, isn't it?
Re consistency: Minifiers take care of size. And in this example it's pretty irrelevant.

Comment: CDN and caching will eliminate that delay in practice, but with jQuery it is common to place all scripts at the end of body... was just saying it not essential/problematic as you implied :)

Comment: Might as well move to the shorter DOM ready handler too... Saves quite a few characters and is also the latest standard :)

Comment: But less readable. And those characters are *really* irrelevant in this question ;)

Comment: Standards are standards. If you know them it is just as readable :P The shorter version also provides `jQuery` as the first parameter, so you can do `jQuery(function($){...});` to get a locally scoped `$` :)